# mini-flux system inside the flux structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Most of the legit tutorial/demo out there are all talking about using Flux as a framework for the whole app. I am wondering if anyone has experience of building an app with multiple mini-flux-components. Because I am thinking in this way it might be easier to extract the mini-system out and then apply to other projects.

What do you guys think??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nothing stopping you from instantiating multiple `dispatchers`**, essentially creating multiple "instances" of Flux. The Dispatcher doesn't use any globals, so each instance is completely independent of the others.

I would **avoid registering a *Store* with more than dispatcher**, for the sake of keeping things simple and maintainable. To this end, a dispatcher should only span a fully modular domain of the application where the Stores under it's purview don't need to communicate with stores wired to different dispatchers.